# perform two actions on onClick event on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, use-state

I'm trying to set an onClick  event to perform  two actionss, the first action is to update a state in the  child component and then update a state in the parent component, please share ideas on how to achieve this

Comment: Put code to do both in the onClick event..

Comment: return updated state from first function and then pass that state to second function as argument

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a callback state like this:

```
 const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [parent, setParent] = useState(0);
    
        const doSomething = () => {
          setCounter(1);
        }
        
        useEffect(() => {
           console.log('Do something after counter has changed', counter);
        setPrent(2);
        }, [counter]);
```